# Rails: Capybara execute js to save value to browser's local storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am running tests using `Rspec, Capybara, Cucumber, and Selenium webdriver`. For my app, if a user is a first time visitor to the site, a pop-up appears after 10 seconds, asking the user to signup for a newsletter. Whether the user signs up or not, a value gets saved to the browsers `local storage`, specifying that the user has viewed the pop-up (I do this so it doesn't popup every visit).

For some of my tests the popup gets in the way since it loads for every new scenario. What I want to do is before a scenario is run, to save a value to local storage before running the test, this way the popup doesn't appear. So far I have a before hook that specifies which scenarios should not have the popup:

```
Before('@no-newsletter') do
  page.execute_script "window.localStorage.setItem('subscribed','viewed');"
end
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
```

I can't figure out how to correct this issue and save a value to local storage. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to visit a url before you can set a value in localStorage for that domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

localStorage is stored for specific document origin - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.  Therefore you need to visit a URL for a specific origin before you can execute JS to store anything in the local storage (otherwise you'd be attempting to set local storage associated with `about:blank` which doesn't make sense)

```
Before('@no-newsletter') do
  page.visit('/something') # visit a valid location to set localStorage
  page.execute_script "window.localStorage.setItem('subscribed','viewed');"
end
```